# Non Required field on Scaffolding .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Learning .NetCore 6 - and i don't know why but om my MVC Create Page for my model, all fields are been shown as required where I actually didn't set any to be required.
My goal was just to set one of them to not be required

```
    public class CarViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

the html generated

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Brand" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Brand" class="form-control" required="false" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Brand" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Model" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Model" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Model" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Code" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Identifier" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Identifier" class="form-control" required="false" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Identifier" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

why are all fields been marked as required on submit ?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove below line from your project.csproj file.

```
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app) to know more.

And other required by add attribute `[Required]`

**Or**

Set one of them to not be required by add `?` :

```
 public string? Brand { get; set; }
```